# Filtering in Maven War Plugin

Tags: java, maven, maven-war-plugin

I don´t understand the following filter configuration for the maven war plugin. Could somebody explain me please, what they are doing? I have marked the code with First Example and Second Example

```
    <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <webResources>
                    <!--First Example-->
                    <resource>
                        <directory>/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.xml</include>
                            <include>**/*.xhtml</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                    <!--Second Example-->  
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                        <filtering>false</filtering>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
                            <exclude>**/*.xhtml</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 9):

I know this is kind of old question, but the other answer is so misleading that I felt I should clarify it...

**Filtering** in Maven usually denotes a concept of **substituting property placeholders** in processed text files (e.g. replacing occurrences of `${project.version}` with your project's actual version).

Your configuration can be read as: *Every XML and/or XHTML file should undergo property substitution when copied to the target directory, while everything else should be simply copied to the target directory without any processing.*

Some further reading:

- [filtering of resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html#)
- [filtering of webapp resources](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html)
- [filtering of web.xml](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/faq.html#filtering)

Answer (score -2):

Filtering in war plugin configuration is used to include/exclude chosen directories/files.
Given configuration is as follows:

```
<resource>
    <directory>/src/main/webapp</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
         <include>**/*.xml</include>
         <include>**/*.xhtml</include>
    </includes>
</resource>
```

Filtering configured above is set for /src/main/webapp as root directory
There is as flag called filtering which is used to enable/disable filtering

```
<include>**/*.xml</include>
```

means that all .xml files within any subdirectory of root directory (/src/main/webapp) will be included. Next include means the same but with .xhtml files

```
<resource>
   <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
   <filtering>false</filtering>
   <excludes>
      <exclude>**/*.xml</exclude>
      <exclude>**/*.xhtml</exclude>
   </excludes>
</resource>
```

All parameters are the same as in previous part except exclude which have opposite meaning to include
${basedir} is used when root directory i located in different path then pom.xml. In above example it's not neccesary

Hope this'll help to understand it